# Добавление onMouseOver к элементу с передачей самого элемента в качестве аргумента

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api, reactjs

Использую [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps), и встроенные компоненты `GoogleMap` и `InfoWindow`, где последний заполняю следующим содержимым:

```
      <div className = 'infoWindow' onMouseOver={()=>{
        $('.infoWindow').find('.additionalData').slideToggle();
      }}>
        <h3>{curr.name}</h3>
        <div className='imgContainer'>
          <img src={icon} alt=''/>
        </div>
        <div className='additionalData'>
          <div className = 'phoneNumber'>{curr.phone}</div>
          <div className = 'address'>{curr.address}</div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Получается, что при наведении на `.infoWindow` начинают слайдиться сразу все `.additionalData`. Пробовал индексировать id, но `onMouseOver` привязывается уже к первому элементу и при наведении на любой из других слайдится первый.
Наверняка есть способ передать текущий элемент в функцию и там уже работать с ним, но не могу найти, с jQuery знаком пару дней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный селект `$('.infoWindow').find('.additionalData').slideToggle();` всегда будет возвращать `.additionalData` из первого найденного `.infoWindow`. Вам нужно искать `.additionalData` относительно текущего DOM элемента, а не по всей странице.

Насколько я помню react первым аргументов передает объект события. У него есть свойство `target` которое ссылает на DOM элемент в котором произошло событие (т.е. на нужный вам `.infoWindow`)

Итого получаем:

```
<div className = 'infoWindow' onMouseOver={(event)=>{
    $(event.target).find('.additionalData').slideToggle();
}}>
// Пропущено
</div>
```